# Move Sitecore Items From Dev To Test

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, devops, tds

I wanted to some automated solution which would move our sitecore items from Dev env to Test CD env .I am  planning to use Octopus for moving .Net stuffs from Dev to Test and What I want when this movement happen simultaneously our sitecore items gets moved from Dev Cm to Test Cd . Can TDS help us on this or is there any other easy way around . Please help on this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deb, perhaps I am misreading your question, but it appears you want to get item information into a CD environment? That is typically done via publishing, as your items are only really deployed to a master database and then publishing transfers them to the Web database referenced by a content delivery server.

If you are not running a Test content management system and only a test CD instance, then you can achieve the item transfer by having a publication target within Sitecore which targets your Test CD web database. You would need to add this to your connection strings and also in the database as a publishing instance, and then your CM can pubish to Test CD

Comment: Thanks . We are planning our .Net dev team would work on Web DB to read required contents and while publishing .Net stuffs we will move the contents To Test CD . So looking for some automated type of tool .

Comment: As mentioned, Deb, if you are only running a content delivery in test, you do not need any automated tool to push content to your CD. It can read either from Web or a separate publishing database. Sitecore can publish to multiple targets.

Comment: Thanks ..actually  in test we ll ve CM and CD both for testing purpose

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you don't copy directly from dev to test.  Instead, you serialize your items and put them into source control with your solution.  Then your deployment process will sync the environment you are deploying to with the serialized items. [TDS](http://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/) and [Unicorn](https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn) are the two main tools used for this.

You can either sync directly against the serialized items or you can build packages that are then deployed with something like [Sitecore.Ship](https://github.com/kevinobee/Sitecore.Ship)

Comment: There is one more tool that could be used for Sitecore items deployment. It  is Sitecore Courier https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-Courier
It is quite good when you need incremental updates of your data on servers.

Comment: Thanks . I will check on this . Can we integrate TDS with our deployment toools ?